# CS50 "BLUR" PSET 4

Tags: c, filter, cs50, blur

when I run make filter it compiles but when I'm running it it does this... helpers.c:104:39: runtime error: -nan is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    float red = 0, blue = 0, green = 0;
    int average_red[height][width], average_blue[height][width], average_green[height][width];
    float count = 0;
    

    // LOOP HEIGHT
    for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
    {
        // LOOP WIDTH
        for (int j = 0; width > j; j++)
        {
            // LOOP 3x3 PIXELS
            for (int x = i - 1; i > x; x++)
            {
                for (int y = j - 1; j > y; y++)
                {
                    // ONLY ACCEPT PIXELS WITHIN THE IMAGE
                    if ((x >= 0 && x < height) || (y >= 0 && y < width))
                    {
                        red += image[x][y].rgbtRed;
                        blue += image[x][y].rgbtBlue;
                        green += image[x][y].rgbtGreen;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // GET THE AVERAGE
            average_red[i][j] = limit(round(red / count));
            average_blue[i][j] = limit(round(blue / count));
            average_green[i][j] = limit(round(green / count));
            // RESET ALL VALUE
            red = 0;
            blue = 0;
            green = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    // LOOP HEIGHT
    for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)
    {
        // LOOP WIDTH
        for (int j = 0; width > j; j++)
        {
            // RETURN THE VALUE BY COLOR TO RESPECTIVE PIXELS
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = average_red[i][j];
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average_blue[i][j];
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average_green[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Generally, reset variables *before* you use them, not *after*.

Comment: You inner loops `x` and `y` have the wrong condition, and on the right side and the bottom of the image they won't sum any pixels, and so you divide by `0` count. It should be `x <= i + 1` and `y <= j + 1`.

Comment: Can you point to which line 104 is? I'm assuming that this is from the "helpers.c" file?

Comment: Aside your loops like `for (int i = 0; height > i; i++)` are unidiomatic and hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

for the inner loops I used

```
for (int col = i - 1; i + 2 > col; col++)
        {
            for (int row = j - 1; j + 2 > row; row++)
            {
                if (col >= 0 && col < height && row >= 0 && row < width)
                {
                    red += image[col][row].rgbtRed;
                    blue += image[col][row].rgbtBlue;
                    green += image[col][row].rgbtGreen;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
```